# Units after fourier transform of barrier

Tags: fft

Suppose you have a voltage pulse: V(x) = v for x in [-L/2, L,2] else V(x)=0. The volatage has unit [V]. If you do a Fourier transform of this signal you get:

V(k) = v*L *sinc(pi*Lk)

After the Fourier transform, the voltage has unit [Vm] because the unit of L is [m]. However, if I search on the internet then I find results that the unit does not change after Fourier transformation (which sounds also more logical to me)...

Concrete: what is the unit of my voltage pulse after Fourier transformation?

Answer (score 0):

After a fft you no longer have voltage, instead you have an array where each element represents a frequency and the value of each array element is a complex number to which you can obtain the magnitude 0<->1 of the strength of that frequency along with the phase shift of that frequency

Interestingly with this fft output you can perform an inverse fft call to return back to you your original signal, in your case your voltage pulse train